# Switch from child shape to group in order to select

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I'm having a real problem integrating two separate shape manipulation functions.

This pseudo code works (I've stripped some functionality out for simplicity). It loops through a list of object names in column N, selects the object with that name, then colours it in.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim clr As Range
Dim i As Integer
'
    Range("R2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("O2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    For i = 2 To 300
        Set clr = Sheets("SheetName1").Range("O" & i)
        Sheets("SheetName1").Shapes.Range(Array(Cells(i, 14))).Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(1, 2, 3) 'RGB actually calculated - just go with it!
    Next i
end sub
```

and THIS code works; this selects the group name for the objects in the previous loop, plus a title and legend object, copies it and pastes it as a picture object on another tab:

```
sub Macro2()        
    Sheets("SheetName1").Shapes.Range(Array("WholeGroupItem")).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy ' << ----
    Sheets("Destination1").Select
    Range("B7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
End Sub
```

However, when I combine the two together and run in a single macro, I get an error at the stage marked `' << ----` reporting:

> copy method of groupobject class failed

It's almost like there's a problem de-selecting the last child object and selecting (copying) the parent group. I've tried throwing in a random `range("A1").select` but it doesn't make any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of Shapes, first do a for each, get each shape and then copy the range. There's no flattening of nested list in VBA.

Comment: In the 1st stage I'm actually pulling the cell colour (rather than 1,2,3) so that's why I'm looping through cells. In the second stage; I want to paint the entire shape plot as one picture: it's actually a map so I don't want weird clipping. I'll give your suggestion a go though...

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Patience!

Literally. After the initial colour call, I added a `Calculate` line to force update of various conditional formats etc. - which admittedly I hadn't included in the original post as it wasn't obviously an issue.

All sorted now. Hopefully this may help some other soul in the future.